# AudioInfo Is not recognized (ruby-audioinfo gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, audio, mp3

I get the following error when trying to use the AudioInfo class (that comes with the ruby-audioinfo gem):

```
uninitialized constant PlaylistsController::AudioInfo
```

I have bundled the gem.  Have restarted my server as well.  Mp3Info seems to be working fine as I am using ruby-mp3info gem as well. Using rails 4 and latest gem version: https://github.com/moumar/ruby-audioinfo

Answer (score 1):

You need to require the gem for your PlaylistsController class. Try putting this at the top of your file:

```
    require 'audioinfo'
```